# What is the best way to defer a Message?

Tags: java, scala, akka

I have an actor "ItemProvider" which can  receive a "getItems" message.
A ItemProvider manages Items of a project. So I can have several "getItems" messages requesting Items for project A and other "getItems" messages requesting Items for project B.

The first time "itemProvider" gets such a message it needs to call a service to actually get the items
(this can take a minute the service returns a future so it won't block the actor) . During this wait period other "getItems" messages can arrive.

A project "ItemProvider" caches the "Items" it receives from the service.
So after the 1 minute loading time it can serve the items instantly.

I am pretty sure the "ItemProvider" should use Akka's become feature. But how should it handle the clients it can not serve right away?

I can think of the following options:

1. ItemProvider holds a List pendingMessages. And the messages it cannot serve are added to this list. When ItemProvider is "ready" it will handle the pending clients
2. ItemProvider sends the message back to its parent. And the parent will reissue the message
3. ItemProvider uses the scheduler. And gets the message in the future again.
4. Maybe not use become but use the AbstractFSM class?

   Does anybody know the best Akka way to implement ItemProvider?

Comment: I looks like it can serve them, because you're using `Future`, but that may be redundant work if, for example, you get the same request in a very short period of time. You need a way to tell the subsequent requests that you already have a response in the making. So, yeah, you may need a `Map` from request to future, and when a new request comes, check with the `Map` and if it has a `Future` for that request make it so that you send the `Future` response to this client, too.

Comment: I don't think you can use `become`. You need `become` when you have a state machine, and you have more than one state machine. There's a state machine for each separate request, with two states: fetching and fetched.

Comment: I am a totally beginner to akka. But I do not see why I can't put the clients on a pending list. When the items are ready the Itemprovider can send all waiting clients their result. this seems to me a good choice

Comment: Ah, you can do that, too. Sure.

Comment: @jack, I can code up a scala based solution to your problem if you don't mind it not being in java.  Let me know if you want to see that.

Comment: that would be awesome!!!! I am learning scala so it would also help me with my scala learning

Comment: @jack, I have posted a possible solution for you.  Sorry it took so long.  I was busy with other stuff.

Comment: @cmbaxter thanx you so much! answers like yours make learning akka a pleasure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below you will find one possible way to structure the actors to meet your requirements.  In this solution, I will use an actor instance per project to cache the items specific to that project.  Then, I will use a routing actor that will receive requests to get items for a project and delegate to the correct child actor that handles the cache for that project.  In the actual caching actor, you will see that I have used stash/unstash to handle deferring the requests until the items to cache have been loaded (which I am simulating in the code).  The code is as follows:

```
import akka.actor._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import akka.pattern._
import concurrent.duration._ 
import akka.util.Timeout

class ItemProviderRouter extends Actor{
  import ItemProvider._

  def receive = {
    case get @ GetItems(project) =>

      //Lookup the child for the supplied project.  If one does not
      //exist, create it
      val child = context.child(project).getOrElse(newChild(project))
      child.forward(get)
  }

  def newChild(project:String) = {
    println(s"creating a new child ItemProvider for project $project")
    context.actorOf(Props[ItemProvider], project)
  }

}

object ItemProvider{
  case class GetItems(project:String)
  case class Item(foo:String)
  case class LoadedItems(items:List[Item])
  case object ClearCachedItems
  case class ItemResults(items:List[Item])
}

class ItemProvider extends Actor with Stash{
  import ItemProvider._  

  //Scheduled job to drop the cached items and force a reload on subsequent request
  import context.dispatcher
  context.system.scheduler.schedule(5 minutes, 5 minutes, self, ClearCachedItems)

  def receive = noCachedItems

  def noCachedItems:Receive = {
    case GetItems(project) =>
      stash()      
      fetchItems(project)
      context.become(loadingItems)


    case ClearCachedItems =>
      //Noop
  }

  def loadingItems:Receive = {
    case get:GetItems => stash

    case LoadedItems(items) =>
      println(s"Actor ${self.path.name} got items to cache, changing state to cachedItems")
      context.become(cachedItems(items))
      unstashAll()    

    case ClearCachedItems => //Noop      
  }

  def cachedItems(items:List[Item]):Receive = {
    case GetItems(project) =>
      sender ! ItemResults(items)

    case ClearCachedItems =>
      println("Clearing out cached items")
      context.become(noCachedItems)       

    case other =>
      println(s"Received unexpected request $other when in state cachedItems")          
  }

  def fetchItems(project:String){
    println(s"Actor ${self.path.name} is fetching items to cache")

    //Simulating doing something that results in a Future
    //representing the items to cache    

    val fut = Future{
      Thread.sleep(5000)
      List(Item(s"hello $project"), Item(s"world $project"))
    }

    fut.map(LoadedItems(_)).pipeTo(self)
  }
}
```

And then to test it:

```
object ItemProviderTest extends App{
  import ItemProvider._
  val system = ActorSystem("test")
  import system.dispatcher
  val provider = system.actorOf(Props[ItemProviderRouter])

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)
  for(i <- 1 until 20){
    val afut = provider ? GetItems("a")
    val bfut = provider ? GetItems("b")

    afut onSuccess{
      case ItemResults(items) => println(s"got items list of $items for project a")
    }

    bfut onSuccess{
      case ItemResults(items) => println(s"got items list of $items for project b")
    }    
  }
}
```

For simplicity purposes, I'm using an actual actor to do the routing as opposed to a custom router, but you could also implement a custom router here instead if performance (i.e. the mailbox hit) matters to you.

Comment: would it make sense to put the fetchItems in a fetchItemsLoader actor? Would I gain anything?

Comment: @jack, sure, if you wanted to separate out the loading part from the caching and serving part then I don't see why not.  If that's the case then you could just either use an `ask (?)` there and get the future and pipe back to self as I was doing in the example or use a `tell (!)` and wait for the response directly without needing a future.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Akka's [Stash feature](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#stash) ([usage example](https://gist.github.com/drewhk/5907823)). 
Below is (untested) code to stash getItems messages while requesting the actual items from the server and then process all the getItems messages after the server request is completed

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, Stash}

class ItemProviderActor extends Actor with Stash {
  private[this] itemsOpt : Option[Items] = None

  def receive = processing

  def processing: Receive = {
    case m:GetItems => {
      if(itemsOpt.nonEmpty) {
        // respond immediately
        itemsOpt.foreach(sender() ! _)
      }
      else {
        // Stash current request and initiate cache update
        context.become(retrivingData)
        stash()

        // Will send future results of item retrieval as a message to self
        retrieveItems().pipeTo(self)
      }
    }
  }

  def retrivingData: Receive = {
    case m: Items => 

      // items are retrieved, update cache
      itemsOpt = Option(m)

      // resume normal processing
      context.become(processing)

      // put all pending item requests back to actor's message queue
      unstashAll()


    case m:GetItems => 
      // busy retrieving items, store request to serve later
      stash()
  }

  def retrieveItems() : Future[Items] = {
    ???
  }

}
```

Comment: this looks very much like what I need. I try it out tomorrow! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The client should resend the idempotent request on a schedule until it receives a satisfactory answer or times out.

Whether you need more ItemProviders, or the ItemProvider batches requests depends on the nature of the resource being queried. If you can only issue 1 request per minute then the requests should be batched in the ItemProvider. However it is the client's responsibility to ensure it continues to request an answer until it is satisfied. It should not rely on the ItemProvider to reliably remember the request.